# Espresso Tutorial for android automation

Tags: android-espresso

I am using Appium to automate an Android app. Now, I am asked to use 
Espresso, which I have no idea about at all. I don't have any idea on Android studio too. Can somebody provide me any links for best Espresso tutorial from scratch for beginners?

Answer (score 0):

We have written a whole framework over Espresso to avoid the hassle to beginners of dealing with it. It's called Barista, [here's its link](https://github.com/SchibstedSpain/Barista), and I hope you enjoy it!